# Should my routers login be visible on my public IP?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I portforwarded my router a while back and today I decided to remove my port forwards as I was not using them. I removed them all and went on my Public IP to check if they were removed and instead of chrome giving me an error or blank page, I see my router login. Is this safe? How can I remove it? I removed all my port forwards, none are left

Comment: Are you still connected to the router via Wifi? If so your router could automatically be serving you the "internal" page. If you have a phone with cellular data turn off the Wifi and try to connect to your public IP.

Comment: I mentioned this in my last comment but it seems that it was something with my router. a loopback or something. I had a friend try to connect and he gets a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

Router login is an option of the router that allows you to change parameters
*on the router* from the internet. It has nothing to do with port forwarding,
and is a very big security risk.

Enter your router's login page from your local network, search for this option
and disable it. For good measure, reboot the router and verify that the page
is no longer accessible from the internet.

In case of difficulties, let us know the model of the router.

Comment: Hi, I dont understand what you mean I should disable it? I have already removed all my portforwards. Im using a D link DSL-G2562DG

Comment: @Iacopo look. If some bot got your public-ip and see the login page, there is a high chance of bruteforce attack. It means the bot will try hundreds of passwords and can guess yours too. In that case, the hacker can change the dns of your router! If so, your web traffic can be compromised.  He can setup phishing to get your credentials!!

Comment: @Iacopo there is a setting for disabling remote access. If you can not find it, you should get a new router that has it.

Comment: The option might be called "Remote Management" on your router. See if something similar to [this procedure](https://www.dlink.com.vn/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-remote-management-on-my-dir-868l-router-2/) exists on your router.

Comment: Hi, there is nothing like that. I have gone to each tab and setting to check if there is anything similar and I have nothing.

Comment: It's hard to find a manual for your router. Perhaps this option is in *MAINTENANCE > Access Controls > Services* and disable WAN on HTTP. See [link](http://files.dlink.com.au/products/DSL-2750B/REV_T/SetupGuides/How_do_I_enable_remote_management.pdf).

Comment: @Iacopo AFAIK, no router manufacturer defaults the WebAdmin to be accessible from WAN... you'll want to refer to your router's manual, which should be able to be found on DLink's support page for that router _(worst case: reset the router to defaults)_. The only two ways a router's WebAdmin should be accessible from WAN are either via an SSH tunnel that maps a local port to the `localhost` of the router or via a VPN connection, where the router is the VPN server.

Comment: JW0914 I plugged in my spare router that is default setup and even from there I could still access it. I tried disconnecting my PC and tried accessing my public ip via my phone and it still shows up. I asked my friend to put my IP in his browser and He tells me it gives him an error. Could this be a loopback in my own network? @harrymc HTTP is by default set on LAN

Comment: The answer is then that you are accessing the router through the LAN and not through the internet. Somehow you are entering a URL that points to the local IP router, not its public IP. In fact, only some consumer routers support loopbacks of the type local->internet->local, many don't.